# Close connection to a database after finishing the query

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

So, basically,someone was telling me today that the way I Query my database was bad before I never close the connection after finishing and thus I probably had many open connection with the database running simultaneously.

I looked online however, I did not get a straight answer. I am using MySQL Mariadb.
and this is how I am doing it

```
db = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', username, passwd, db='mydb') 

# and actually call this function and pass query
def db_execute(query):
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    db.commit()
```

is this decent? how can I close the connection after I finish? what's better?

Comment: Is this a long running app that will need the same connection later, or a short script which will end soon? Are you reopening the connection again later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    db = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', username, passwd, db='mydb') 

    # and actually call this function and pass query
    def db_execute(query):
        cursor = db.cursor()
        try:   
           cursor.execute(query)
           db.commit()
        #You can also catch any exceptions you are interested in here
        finally:
           cursor.close()
           db.close()
```

`Finally` block gets executed even if you code throws an exception, hence your connection is always closed even if something unexpected happens. If you do not use finally and there is an exception in your code before the close statement, the connection remains open, which is undesired.

Comment: if I have multiple queries, should I   cursor.close() db.close() after every query or at the end of all the queries? or maybe do cursor.close() and use db.close() at the very end?

Comment: Closing database connection and re-establishing is an over head in that case. Ideally a production application which has good amount of db interaction should use a connection pool

Comment: if I have only few connections, let's say 5 connections every time the scripts run. is it okey to close the database at every connection or should I close it once I finish with the five connections and terminate the script.

Comment: You could close the connections as soon as you have finished using them like the code shows. There is no point keeping the other connections open when they aren't being used.

Answer (score 0):

Promptly close anything *inside* the database.  This applies to "cursors", "transactions", etc.

As for `disconnect()` (however it is spelled), the rules are different.

- Do *not* do a connect-disconnect around each SQL statement; this is terribly inefficient.
- In a web application, *do* connect at early in the "web page" and either disconnect when finished, or let the containing code (PHP, etc) deal with closing when it goes away.  Web pages are short-lived and cannot leave "state" for the next page when the user clicks a link.
- In a long-running application, be aware that after some number of minutes (configurable) of not touching the database, the connection to the database will be closed.  If you then try to do some SQL, you will get some form of error.  For such rare applications, you may need to connect+disconnect more than once.  And you may as well do them at times convenient to the application.

Generally having lots of idle connections is "not a problem".  However, if it exceeds `max_connections`, newcomers will get an error about 'cannot connect'.

"Connection pooling" adds another dimension to this discussion.  I won't go there.

Answer (score -1):

`cursor.close()` and then `db.close()`

Comment: Please add a short explanation to your answer.